# Discord.js how can I create an invite for every guild my bot is in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command, where I can get every guild invite that the bot is currently in.
Current code:

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'invite')) {
  let invite = client.guilds
   .createInvite({
    maxAge: 0, // 0 = infinite expiration
    maxUses: 0, // 0 = infinite uses
   })
   .catch(console.error);
  message.channel.send(invite);
 }
});
```

Error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

Comment: Note that Discord allows bots to create invites to guild only when they are allowed to, ie. a guild administrator does a command to create a new invite. Creating invites without permission from the guild's moderators/admins isn't allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```js
 var invites = []; // starting array
    message.client.guilds.cache.forEach(async (guild) => { // iterate loop on each guild bot is in

      // get the first channel that appears from that discord, because
      // `.createInvite()` is a method for a channel, not a guild.
      const channel = guild.channels.cache 
        .filter((channel) => channel.type === 'text')
        .first();
      if (!channel || guild.member(client.user).hasPermission('CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE') return;
      await channel
        .createInvite({ maxAge: 0, maxUses: 0 })
        .then(async (invite) => {
          invites.push(`${guild.name} - ${invite.url}`); // push invite link and guild name to array
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
      console.log(invites);
    });
```

---

As an example, this is what *I* got after running the command:

[image: Discord Example]

---

- [`GuildChannel.createInvite()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=createInvite)
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: TypeError: client.guilds.createInvite is not a function

Comment: I am using V12, and client.gulds.createInvite is not a function

Comment: `createInvite()` is a method for a `GuildChannel`, not a `Guild`